# Is it possible to communicate with an iPhone over a serial-bt-bridge?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, serial-port

I have a device with an rs-232 port and a btm222-bt-serial bridge. Is it possible to communicate with an iPhone using this setup?

Does the iPhone have the Bluetooth serial port profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not directly possible.

You will have to change the RS322 device firmware (and possibly hardware) to be compatible with Apple  accessory (joining Apple MFi will give more details).
So it can be done if you can do a ground up design change.

Comment: ok thank you. an full redesign is not possible as the hardware is used for other existing devices too. but i also thought so in apples restrictive politic and the lack of bt-profiles.

Comment: sure - pls accept / voteup the answer if it was useful. - thanks!